# When does a banished creature act in initiative once the concentration on Banishment ends?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, initiative

I have a question regarding the *[banishment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment)* spell in Dungeons & Dragons 5e, when can the banished target act? The spell duration end, the target acts in her turn? Rolls a new initiative because he was out of the table?

My point of view is that the target keeps the same initiative and when the spell ends, he acts depending of his initiative before/after the spell ended, but I'm not sure, and if the spells ends the concentration with an attack of opportunity?

Imagine the banished target was the next in the initiative order, does he act?

Comment: What is "if the spells ends the concentration with an attack of opportunity" supposed to mean? Damage can trigger a Concentration check, but this seems like an oddly specific statement. Who do you see taking this attack of opportunity and why?

Answer (score 8):

### *[Banishment](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/banishment)* does not change initiative

Spells do only what they say they do: *Banishment* says nothing about initiative so it does nothing about initiative. Incidentally, AFAIK, there is nothing in D&D 5e that changes initiative once it’s been established.

If concentration is maintained, the spell can last 10 rounds.. Therefore, it is almost certain that the combat the Banished creature was a part of will be over since a combats rarely last 5 rounds, let alone 10.

A DM could consider this an entirely new combat and have everyone roll initiative or they could consider it a continuation in which case everyone’s initiative stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Target keeps their initiative.

If target comes back before their turn, they can take their turn normally during that round.

If target comes back after their turn, they cannot take their turn during that round. They can act later in the next round on their turn.

Example:

> Suppose the banished target has initiative of 15, and the caster 10. The target's turn comes before the caster.
>
> 1. On round 1, initiative count 10, the caster casts *banishment* on target
> 2. On round 2, initiative count 15, the target turn comes first, but they can't act (to affect the combat)
> 3. After target's turn ends (initiative counts 15+), concentration ends for *banishment* (for any reason)
> 4. The target reappears, but the initiative continues after target, effectively skipping their turn